# Is it common for Yongnuo flashes to overheat and stop working?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, yongnuo

I have had a Yongnuo Macro Ring Lite YN14EX flash for a little over a year. I have used it 4 times; it worked great. The battery door does not close all the way now, but after looking at many reviews this is common. The other day I loaded batteries in and turned it on, and the flash turned off. Tried again, same results. After changing to fresh batteries, it came on and made some funny sounds I had never heard, and then turned itself off. I took batteries out and they were so hot I could not hold them. Now it will not do anything.

Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: To explain the noises: The inverter is working into a short circuit - either the flash capacitor, or something in the inverter circuit itself has shorted out. Do not attempt to mess with it if you needed this explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

That's what Yongnuo and other cheap Chinese flashes sometimes do. It's why many of us consider them "disposable" and always have a spare handy if  we are using them for critical jobs. In the long run, you usually come out ahead buying four or five comparable Yongnuo flashes for the same price as one Canon or Nikon or Sony or etc. flash, since you can use more than one of them at a time until they crap out. Just always be sure to have one more than you need for a shoot. It's also not a bad idea to have at least one first party (Canon, Nikon, etc.) flash at hand just in case.

Comment: Thanks Michael...will consider that...I have a good Canon regular flash and only do Macro when the occasion arises.